# Android Http Request Error

Tags: java, android, http, request, httprequest

I had tried many ways to make an http request in android. Logcat keeps giving me errors no matter what i do. I need some help here. I added

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

to manifest file
I had checked my connection and it says it is connected...

code :

```
package com.example.gpschat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String[] messages;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String m = "";
        try {
            m = excutePost();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("gilad", m);
        messages = m.split(",");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chat);
        for (String message : messages)
        {
            lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setId(1);
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            tv.setText(message);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            (ll).addView(tv);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public static String excutePost() throws IOException
      {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://laurawharton.com/gps/getM.php"));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            String responseString = out.toString();
            //..more logic
            return responseString;
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
      }
}
```

error:

```
09-02 11:43:10.873: W/dalvikvm(1234): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ac8ba8)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): Process: com.example.gpschat, PID: 1234
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpschat/com.example.gpschat.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at com.example.gpschat.MainActivity.excutePost(MainActivity.java:89)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at com.example.gpschat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-02 11:43:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     ... 11 more
09-02 11:43:16.833: I/Process(1234): Sending signal. PID: 1234 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you search for this Problem in Google first?
Stack Overflow 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0):

try with ***AsyncTask***

I was just wanted write short comment, but I'm not able to write a comment. I'm sorry.

***AsyncTask*** will help you.

If you need a tutorial, take a look.

link : [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)